# View not rendering images correctly in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display images in a view but the images are not getting rendered according to the x and y coordinates provided.

The var all_dim[i] is a string of the form X_coord,Y_coord, Height, Width

```
public styles = StyleSheet.create({
scroll_layouts: {
  height: 100,
  zIndex: 40,
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
},
Lay_view: {
  width: 100,
  height: 200,
  transform: [
    { translateX: 0},
    { translateY: 0},
  ]
} 
});

public displayLayout()
{
  if(this.props.index == 2)
  {
    var to_disp = [];
    var all_layouts = this.props.data_string.split('&');
    for(var j = 0;j < all_layouts.length - 1;j++)
    {          
      var all_dim = all_layouts[j].split(";");          
      var xyz=[];
      var images_arr = this.props.arr_img;  
      for(var i = 0;i < all_dim.length - 1;i++)
        {                
          var image_fill = images_arr[i].uri;
          var indivi_elems = all_dim[i].split(',');  
          var h = parseFloat(indivi_elems[2]);
          var w = parseFloat(indivi_elems[3]);
          var xc = parseFloat(indivi_elems[0]);
          var yc = parseFloat(indivi_elems[1]);              
          xyz.push(<Image key = {i} source = {{uri: image_fill}} style = {{height: h, width: w,transform: [{ translateX: xc},{ translateY: yc},{scaleX:1},{scaleY:1}]}}/>);
        } 
        var hjk = <View key = {j} style = {this.styles.Lay_view}>{xyz}</View>;
        to_disp.push(hjk);
    }
    return (          
      <ScrollView horizontal = {true} style = {this.styles.scroll_layouts}>     
        {to_disp}      
      </ScrollView>)
  }
}
```

I expect the images to be displayed according to the coordinates provided and not one below the other.

**Expected layout of images in output**

[image]

**Output rendered**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The children of the view should have their position prop set to 'absolute'